# Cambiar URL de video si no cumple con cierta cantidad de clicks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contador

Estoy intentando hacer un juego en react js que consiste en lo siguiente, se reproduce un video y cuando el jugador se encuentra en una determinada situación se le aparece un boton al cual debe hacerle una cantidad minima de clicks, de cumplir el objetivo el boton desaparece y el video sigue su reproducción. De lo contrario se cambia la url del video por otro donde se ve al jugador perder. Hago el contador pero no puedo hacer que procese los clicks luego de que se cumpla el tiempo del boton. Entonces si quiero que el video siga cuando el jugador supera la cantidad de clicks me toma siempre que pierde ya que al hacer un click cae fuera de la condicion.

```javascript
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import video from '../../videos/tlou_01.mp4'
import video2 from '../../videos/01.mp4'

export const PlayXp = () => {
    const [pause, setPause] = useState(true)
    const [action, setAction] = useState(false)
    const time = (e) => {
        let time = e.target.currentTime
        if ( time > 3 && time < 10 ) {
            setAction(true)
        } else {
            setAction(false)
        }   
    }
    const handleVideo = () => {
        setPause(!pause)
        { pause ? document.getElementById("vid").play() : document.getElementById("vid").pause() }
        { document.getElementById("vid").addEventListener('timeupdate', time) }
    }
    let contador = 0;
    const handleAction = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        contador++;
        if ( contador >= 3 ) { } 
        else {
            {
            let vid = document.getElementById("vid")
            vid.load()
            vid.setAttribute('autoplay', true)
            vid.setAttribute('src', video2)
            }
        }  
        
    }
      
    return (
        <div className="xp">
            <div className="vid-container">
                {
                    action && <button className="btn-action" onClick={ handleAction }>Click</button> 
                }
                <video className="video" id="vid" muted onClick={handleVideo}>
                    <source src={video} type="video/mp4"></source>
                </video>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: No se exactamente como lo que quieres hacer pero mirando tu código veo unas cuantas cosas que son muy malas prácticas cuando estas trabajando con react. Primeramente estás modificando el DOM de manera directa, lo cual no es nada recomendable cuando trabajas con react. Por otro lado cada vez que renderizas tu componente la variable contador es seteada a cero. Creo que te convendría usarla como `let contador = useRef(0)` y acceder a su valor como `contador.current`.

Comment: Prueba lo de `useRef`, probablemente solucione tu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estoy de acuerdo con uno de los comentarios que se te hicieron. El modificar el DOM de esa manera puede que no sea la adecuada. Puedes encontrar un poco más de información de cómo puedes prevenir eso --> https://ed.team/blog/no-uses-getelementbyid-en-react-usa-las-referencias

En cuanto a tu problema, entiendo que lo que quieres es conseguir el valor del contador una vez que el botón ha desaparecido. Si es así, la forma que lo andas haciendo no es la mejor. Para obtener un valor de una variable y que esta "persista" debes usar un state. Entonces tu código quedaría algo así

```
const [pause, setPause] = useState(true)
const [action, setAction] = useState(false)
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

const handleAction = (e) => {
   setCounter((prevState) => prevState + 1)
}
```

En adición a eso, para "escuchar" cada vez que el state cambia y puedas hacer la condición que quieras en cuanto a los clicks del botón, puedes hacer uso de un useEffect

```
    useEffect(() => {
      if ( counter >= 3 ) { 
        console.log('counter!!')
      }
    }, [counter])
```

Te dejo también estas ligas para que puedas leer acerca de useEffect --> https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html